# Indexing and performance Implications of moving small table into big table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with approximately 2.5 million rows that I am thinking about moving into a much larger table, 35 million rows, with a boolean flag set on the original 2.5 million.

If I wanted to run lots of queries against the 2.5 million records in the new larger table, would adding an index be useful / not cause a full table scan on every query? I know that traditionally indexes aren't helpful in booleans, but since only 7% of the records will be true, I thought it might not require a table scan on every query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps look at using a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html).

**From docs**

> A partial index is an index built over a subset of a table; the subset
>   is defined by a conditional expression (called the predicate of the
>   partial index). The index contains entries for only those table rows
>   that satisfy the predicate.
>
> A major motivation for partial indexes is to avoid indexing common
>   values. Since a query searching for a common value (one that accounts
>   for more than a few percent of all the table rows) will not use the
>   index anyway, there is no point in keeping those rows in the index at
>   all. This reduces the size of the index, which will speed up queries
>   that do use the index. It will also speed up many table update
>   operations because the index does not need to be updated in all cases.
>   Example 11-1 shows a possible application of this idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would be looking at partitioning, if you have a substantial proportion of the table that you want to access efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you do "insert into big select * from small", then all of the rows that came from the small table are likely to be physically close to each other.  After analyzing the table, PostgreSQL will know this, and so will probably choose to use the index on the boolean.

But, if there a lot of churn in the rows then eventually the "true" rows and the "false" rows will become all jumbled up, making use of the index less and less effective, and PostgreSQL will stop using it.

By using partitioning/inheritance, you can keep the rows physically separate (to make sequential scanning on just the small set faster) while making them look like a single set of data when you want to.

Depending on the nature of the queries you run, you might also benefit from adding other columns to the index, keeping the boolean column as the first column.